# how to reorder UIScrollView row like UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiscrollview

I am creating an app in which i need to reorder the uiscrollview rows similar to uitableview so i want to know is that possible to do if yes then how please help me...

Comment: what you want ? reorder ? what do you mean by uiscrollview's row ?

Comment: please elaborate your question.

Comment: yes the reordering similar haapens in UiTableView and UIScrollView row means the images that are used to on scrollview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UITableView` makes it easy to reorder rows, if you need to get the same behavior, in `UIScrollView` you need to do it all yourself...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do something like that then I'm assuming that you didn't consider using a table view with custom UITableViewCells instead? If you are creating something like gallery, try creating a UITableViewCell with a few custom views, which hold images and all additional data you need to display:

.h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ClipView.h"

@interface ClipViewCell : UITableViewCell {

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *clipViews;

- (void)setVisibleClipViewsQuantity:(NSUInteger)quantity;

@end
```

.m file

```
#import "ClipViewCell.h"


@implementation ClipViewCell

@synthesize clipViews;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style
    reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {

  self = [super initWithStyle:style
              reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];

  if (self) {
    self.clipViews = [NSMutableArray array];

    CGFloat xMargin = 5.0f;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      ClipView *clipView = [[[ClipView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xMargin,
                                                                       5.0f,
                                                                       0.0f,
                                                                       0.0f)] autorelease];
      [clipViews addObject:clipView];
      xMargin = clipView.frame.origin.x + clipView.frame.size.width + 5.0f;
      [self addSubview:clipView];
    }
  }
  return self;
}

- (void)setVisibleClipViewsQuantity:(NSUInteger)quantity {
  for (int i = quantity; i < 3; i++) {
    ClipView *clipView = [clipViews objectAtIndex:i];
    clipView.hidden = YES;
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < quantity; i++) {
    ClipView *clipView = [clipViews objectAtIndex:i];
    clipView.hidden = NO;
  }
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected
           animated:(BOOL)animated {
  return;
}

- (void)dealloc {
  self.clipViews = nil;
  [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Where "ClipView" is your custom UIView with displayed data on it.

Then in your UITableView view controller use table view data source methods like:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
  NSInteger number = clips.count % 3 > 0 ? clips.count / 3 + 1 : clips.count / 3;
  return number;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

  ClipViewCell *cell = nil;
  int clipViewsQuantity = 0;

    NSString *reuseIdentifier = @"clipCell";
    if (indexPath.row == [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:0]-1) {
     clipViewsQuantity = myLingoClips.count % 3 > 0 ? myLingoClips.count % 3 : 3;
    }
    else {
      clipViewsQuantity = 3;
    }


  cell = (ClipViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
  if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[ClipViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
  }

  [cell setVisibleClipViewsQuantity:clipViewsQuantity];
  int currentElement = indexPath.row * 3;

  for (int i = 0; i < clipViewsQuantity; i++) {
    ClipView *clipView = [cell.clipViews objectAtIndex:i];
    // do something with the clipView here, like set another image
    currentElement++;
  }

  return cell;
}
```

Using this one you can easily adjust your data model for reordering with standard UITableView functionality.